# IBOutletCollection not connected with UILabels in Storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iboutletcollection

I have an `IBoutletCollection` property connected to several `UILabels` in `Storyboard`:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;
```

called

`NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.labels.count)` after `viewDidLoad`

got `0` as result.

what's the problem I got empty ivar here?

anything wrong with the `Autolayout`? (Yes I'm using it in `Storyboard`)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Make labels strong reference.

Comment: If they are not strong, the reference will be lost immediately after they had been loaded

Comment: Thanks @亚历山大 ! but how come an auto-generated IBoutlet property (dragged from Storyboard to class interface) has weak attribute?

Comment: And if I do this with an xib the weak attribute does not matter ...

Comment: Normally you connect IBOutlets with a weak reference and everything works fine. But if you connect an IBOutletCollection it is a type of NSArray which needs a strong reference to save its elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `weak` to `strong`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(UILabel) NSArray *labels;`